# How to compare a n value to the mean of n-1 ; n-2 ; ... ; n-5?

Tags: r, probability

My question may be silly and I apologize if it is...

I'm working on data that comes from 40 animals monitored during 6 different days at 12-time points each day. I made multiple t-tests to determine at which time points differences between d0 and d-1 to d-5 seemed to appear (not sure about this way to do my analysis as I'm accumulating type I error but it's not my point here). However, having a quite important inter-individual variability, I would like to know for which portion of my population the detected differences are statistically significant. I really don't know where to start as for each individual I'm working on only 6 points for each time point, 1 per day as described above.

I was wondering if this should have been posted on StackOverflow instead but, as I don't even know what kind of test could be used I sent my message here.

Comment: Sounds like you need a generalized linear model, with random effects for intercept and slope.

Comment: Do you mean a generalized linear model with, altogther, individuals, days studied and time points as fixed effects ? I don't really get what should be integrated as random effect nor if any is needed.

Comment: So for each animal you have a total of 6*12 observations? 6 days, 12 measurements per day? What are these measurements? Are they categorical /  ordinal / continuous? And from this you would like to check whether there exist differences between the time points for a given animal and all the days? And do this for each animal? Is this correct?

Comment: I do have 6*12 observations per animal which means I have 2,880 points in total. The datas are continous as it is body temperature measurements. I want to know if it exists a difference comparing one day to the 5 others at the different time points, which I did with t-tests. And for now, I would like to know if the "general" observed difference which appeared at 2 time points are true for my 40 animals or only 35 of them for exemple. I thought I had to take them one by one to check this but maybe there is another solution.
Hoping my issue is a bit clearer now.

Comment: But are you interested in comparing whether temperature is similar between the days without considering time points? Or are you interested in whether the temperatures are similar between the time points of the day without considering days? Or are you interested in whether the temperatures of all the animals are similar for each time point and each day separately?

Comment: I'm interested in comparing temperatures among days and if animals are similar. The question I ask myself is: "Do they all behave the same way regarding temperature variations?". As body temperature follows a circadian rhythm I already know there are differences regarding time of the day and others have described it accuratly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood this correctly, you are interested in comparing the mean temperature of each animal for each day and between the animals. If so, then this is how you would do it in R.

I do not have access to your data so I will just have to make it up. I will use the Ovary data set from the nlme package. I will artificially create two days and add measurement ids for each day. Afterwards I train a mixed model, where measurement is the random effect. Fixed effects are Animal (mare) and Day. The outcome is follicles. This will give you all the combinations for days and animals.

```
library(nlme)

Ovary2=do.call(rbind,
  by(Ovary,list(Ovary$Mare),function(x){
    tmp=nrow(x)
    s1=floor(tmp/2)
    return(
      cbind(x,"Day"=factor(rep(1:2,times=c(s1,tmp-s1))),
            "Measurement"=c(seq(1:s1),seq((s1+1):tmp))
      )
    )
  })
)
Ovary2$Mare=factor(as.numeric(as.character(Ovary2$Mare)),labels=LETTERS[1:11])

summary(lme(follicles~Mare*Day,random=~1|Measurement,data=Ovary2))
```

And this is part of the output

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: Ovary2 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  1611.583 1699.327 -781.7915

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | Measurement
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    1.032887 3.274704

Fixed effects: follicles ~ Mare * Day 
                 Value Std.Error  DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)  15.874539  0.916348 271 17.323702  0.0000
MareB        -7.649660  1.262231 271 -6.060426  0.0000
MareC        -6.034276  1.262231 271 -4.780641  0.0000
MareD       -11.071429  1.237722 271 -8.945007  0.0000
MareE        -6.428571  1.237722 271 -5.193875  0.0000
MareF        -4.214286  1.237722 271 -3.404874  0.0008
MareG        -5.188122  1.262231 271 -4.110278  0.0001
MareH        -5.666310  1.218148 271 -4.651578  0.0000
MareI        -4.980727  1.290032 271 -3.860932  0.0001
MareJ        -4.000000  1.237722 271 -3.231745  0.0014
MareK        -7.111199  1.262231 271 -5.633831  0.0000
Day2         -1.199643  1.218148 271 -0.984809  0.3256
MareB:Day2    0.349304  1.754170 271  0.199128  0.8423
MareC:Day2   11.353490  1.770221 271  6.413601  0.0000
MareD:Day2    4.471429  1.720982 271  2.598184  0.0099
MareE:Day2    4.628571  1.720982 271  2.689494  0.0076
MareF:Day2    5.480952  1.720982 271  3.184782  0.0016
MareG:Day2    1.530622  1.754170 271  0.872562  0.3837
MareH:Day2    8.678914  1.695013 271  5.120264  0.0000
MareI:Day2    2.915325  1.790150 271  1.628537  0.1046
MareJ:Day2    7.866667  1.720982 271  4.571034  0.0000
MareK:Day2    1.453699  1.754170 271  0.828711  0.4080
```

Comment: "Do they all behave the same way regarding temperature variations?" for me this indicates that not only mean but also amplitude and phase of the circadian cycle should be compared.

Comment: @Roland So we would need to estimate a phase and cycle parameter for a sine/cosine curve also?

Comment: Yes, a cosinor model might be nice.

Comment: I think I see your point! I just have a last question, just to be sure to understand your answer. Do the measurement id you added as random effect corresponds, in my case, to the different time sets ? If so, I think I understood your answer. Anyhow, many thanks for all the time you spent helping me today.

Comment: @Roland : I've red about the cosinor method and would have been glad to use it if I've been able to understand how. If you have any nicely explained books/article/stack subject than can be of help regarding the cosinor method, I would be happy to read it!

Comment: @Blue Yes, the measurements are the time points in your case.